# Super Simple C++ Constructor Query

Tags: c++, constructor, parentheses

I everyone I have a real simple question. What is the difference in the following code? (See "With Parentheses" and "Without Parentheses")

```
class class_a{
    public:

        int a_int;

        class_a(){
           a_int = 0;
        }
}

int main( ... ){

    class_a instance_a_first; // Without Parentheses
    class_a instance_a_second(); // With Parentheses

}
```

Comment: The second is a function declaration.

Comment: @JoSo you'd be wrong. :)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This isn't most vexing parse, simply function decl

Comment: It's not really the most vexing parse. That is a slightly more complex but related case. Although most people seem to call it that these days.

Comment: My point is that if you understand the most vexing parse, this will be a walk in the park.

Answer (score 4):

The first one defines a variable called *instance_a_first* of type *class_a*.

The second one declares a function called *instance_a_second* that returns a *class_a* object and takes no parameters.

It's the same as writing :-

```
int one;
```

vs

```
int func();
```

edit: Changed second sentence to say declares instead of defines.

Comment: Why does my formatting to put the names in italics show up as stars?

Comment: because of the underscores, apparently

Comment: Ah ok I guess that makes sense in an annoying kind of way

Comment: The second one **declares** a function; it doesn't **define** it.

Comment: @Pete Becker yes you are correct, I'll update my sloppy answer.

Comment: Ah yes of course! Thanks everyone. :) What would we do without the stackoverflow community?!